# Java - Run Excel using runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, excel, runtime, exec, runtime.exec

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("excel C:\\file.xls");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Doesn't work.
I have to put the full path of excel.exe in order to work.
How can I make it generic (For any Excel Folders/Versions)?
When I run the same line from OS with Windows Run (Start --> Run)
it works. Is there a code in Java to simulate Windows' Run command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you try with the `Desktop` class (api doc [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)) introduced in JDK6 that has the method

```
public void open(File file) throws IOException
```

which is documented as what you want to do:

> Launches the associated application to open the file.
>     If the specified file is a directory, the file manager of the current platform is launched to open it.

Of course this assumes that `.xls` extension is mapped by OS to Excel. Then you can go with

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\file.xls"));
```

Comment: It works but I have problems with spaces in the path. Tried the URI but didn't work.

Comment: maybe you should try embedding the file name between double quotes ".. of course you should escape them: `new File("\"c:\\filename with spaces.xls\"")`

Answer (score 1):

I use
`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C start " + *filename*`
it works for me on Windows platforms

Answer (score 0):

Call the Windows "start.exe" command instead of Excel directly.  Start.exe appears to search paths, etc.  However, it still may not find it if it's not in the path.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using "cmd" instead of "excel", and then pass in an array of params.

For easier debugging, you might also try using ProcessBuilder instead. In my experience it's much nicer to work with: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html