# Redirect a user from my app to Microsoft Office

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, ms-office

I recently moved from Android Development to Java Desktop Development, and I want to redirect the user (at the tap of a button) to a specific Microsoft Office Word document...

Is that possible?

PS: I use Eclipse mars with Google's Window Builder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978369/java-run-excel-using-runtime-getruntime-exec